# Python shutil.copytree saying Destination file it should be copying is missing

Tags: python, shutil

been fighting with this all night.  Worked like 3 days ago, now I can't get it to work for the life of me.

When I try using this

```
 def unzip_file(archiveFile, finalFolder, archiveFolder):
    write_to_log(logFile, 'Unzipping file ' + archiveFile)
    shutil.copy(tempFolder + '/' + archiveFile, archiveFolder)
    try:
        zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(tempFolder + '/'+ archiveFile, 'r')
        zip_ref.extractall(tempFolder)
        zip_ref.close()
        if os.path.exists(finalFolder):
            shutil.rmtree(finalFolder)
        sleep(5)
        shutil.copytree(tempFolder, finalFolder, symlinks=True)
    except zipfile.BadZipFile as e:
        write_to_log(logFile, 'Unzipping file ' + archiveFile + ' failed.  Bad Zip File.')
        shutil.copy(tempFolder + '/' + archiveFile, zipFailFolder)
```

I ALWAYS get the same error no matte what zip file I feed it.  It says the destination file is missing.  The first file in the zip file give me the following error.

```
shutil.Error: [('D:/temp/file.zip', '//DestPath/file.zip', "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '//DestPath/file.zip'")]
```

I am totally out of ideas.  Its not a permission issue, its not the fact the file is missing from the source, the file isn't locked (threw that timer in there just in case).

Anyone run across this before?

Answer (score 2):

That means your `//DestPath` doesn't exist in first place, so `file.zip` can't be created there.

Are those double slashes intentional?

Comment: Yes, they are, its a file share.  I sanitized the folder names because they were long as heck.  The folder is there, I can go look at it.  It creates the folder, then tries to move the first file and errors out.

Comment: Try changing the folder name to some other local folder to test; Also make sure the user running the script has write permissions in the destination folder.  I'm still convinced the problem is in the destination folder @OmegaNine

Comment: After running a few more tests it looks like i gave you some misinformation.  All the files move over fine except the zip file.  The zip file is the actual file i unzipped.  I am thinking maybe its locked still?  Running in more circle, but thank you for making me look at it from another angel.

Comment: I have no idea why this worked, but I moved the zip out of the folder before doing the shutil.copy and it works fine now.  I wouldn't have done that without your help though.  Thanks!